# Call data from JSON using $.ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to get data from an object deserialised from a JSON response. Please check my code below. The AJAX is working fine but don't know how to call data from keys. Please help.

```
{
    "data": {
        "show_page": false,
        "io": true,
        "userslist": [{
            "Captain Hook": {
                "user_logo": "xyxImage.jpg",
                "partner": "Jan 2013",
                "usage": 123000,
                "wise": 73000,
                "server": 50000,
                "status": "bronze",
                "year": 2016,
                "sum": 300000,
                "order": 1
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'js/data.json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function(users, status){
        console.log(users.data.userslist[0]); // Want to print "Captain Hook"
        console.log(users.data.userslist[0].user_logo); // Want to print "logo"
        console.log(users.data.userslist[0].partner); // Want to print "partner"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your data structure the correct code would be `users.data.userslist[index]`. To get the key of the object you would need to use `Object.keys()` and you can then use that to retrieve the other required properties. Try this:

```
success : function(users, status) {
    var user = users.data.userslist[0];
    var key = Object.keys(user)[0];
    console.log(key); // = "Captain Hook"
    console.log(user[key].user_logo); // = "xyxImage.jpg"
    console.log(user[key].partner); // = "Jan 2013"
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xgaun1ax/)